# Selenium python bitbucket

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bitbucket-pipelines

i m trying to integrate selenium python tests on bitbucket pipline :

#bitbucket.yaml

```
`image: python:3.7
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - python --version
          - pip3 install selenium
          - pip3 install webdriver_manager
          - python3.7 Tests/Test1.py`
```

#test.py

```
`from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ServiceChrome
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as ServiceFirefox
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")`
```

**error occured:
**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/110.0.5481/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

any help please for this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you don't have libs or chrome installed on linux

**Try installing:**

- download chrome using wget:

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

- install chrome.(maybe you need to use sudo)

apt install ./google-chrome*.deb

---

**test code:**

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

---

---

**alternative:**
You can go to path and try execute chrome drive:

cd /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/110.0.5481/chromedriver/
./chromedriver

error:

./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0

try install libs.

obs.:

This alternative can cause problems because there are many libs. So best option is the first one

Answer (score -1):

```
+ python3.7 Tests/Test1.py
[WDM] - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/7.05M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
[WDM] - Downloading:  90%|████████▉ | 6.34M/7.05M [00:00<00:00, 66.4MB/s]
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 7.05M/7.05M [00:00<00:00, 71.1MB/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tests/Test1.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    keep_alive,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 117, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/110.0.5481/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Comment: If you want to add further detail to your question, just edit your question. This new post of yours is not an answer but is posted as such.

Comment: Edit your question and update the details you want to include.